# Вывод мета данных Shoutcast трансляции в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, radio

На сайте под управление WP играет онлайн радио, нужно выводить под плеером на странице вот эти данные о текущей композиции: http://149.56.183.178:8034/currentsong?sid=1